# Creating a native iOS App for an existing large .NET application

Tags: ios, .net, ipad

I am creating a native iOS App for a .NET based financial ERP. As a lot of business rules have been written in this system so I would like to keep a single code base and build an app with light front end. Key considerations:
1. Light weight front end, all business logic in back end
2. Extremely user friendly UI
Note that application screens are extremely complex with multiple tabs, Tabs within tabs, navigation on left and right side.

I believe these screens will require significant rework. But my challenge is that users are expected to toggle frequently between desktop and iPAD so they should not get lost.

So I am grappling with these 2 main challenges. Has anyone here solved for this? I need some high level guidance before we proceed.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: It seems like you need user experience guidance before you decide how to build (what technology to use).

Comment: Build a web front end for your ERP and use that. Then it should be able to run on almost any platform.

Comment: It seems like you need user experience guidance before you decide how to build (what technology to use). –  Wain >>                                                     Agreed. I am looking to build a new UI not just the same desktop one (desktop UI itself has many complaints). In other words 2 UIs, same back end. How can I make new UI (iOS App) most efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out www.xamarin.com they allow you to re-use your c# .Net code on iOS. Your back end code could be rewritten and shared between iPad and desktop. You maybe able to share more with some clever code.